# QGIS right of string

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.14, qgis-custom-function

I've been trying to use the Function Editor in QGIS to create a function to return the end of a string following some kind of delimiting character (as I can't find a right-sided equivalent to `strpos`), but get an `Expression is invalid` error when I try to use it.

The function is defined in the Function Editor as follows:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args=2, group='Custom')
def RightOfString(delim, inpstring, feature, parent):
    'Returns values to the right of a '\
    'delimiting character.\n'\
    'Syntax:\n'\
    'RightOfChar([delimiter to find], [Expression])'
    k=str(inpstring).rfind(delim)
    if k > 0:
        return str(inpstring)[k+len(delim):]
    else:
        return str(inpstring)
```

When I try to call this using `RightOfString( '- ', "Description" )` (where `Description` is a field in my table), I get an `Expression is invalid` error. The "More info" part of the Output preview gives the following:

```
Parser Error:


Eval Error:
RightOfString() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

If I remove the `feature, parent` from the definition I still get the same kind of error, in which it thinks I have provided 3 arguments.

Any ideas of how to fix this, or of another formula that can do something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of defining a custom function, you can simply use `regexp_substr()` in the field calculator with the following regex:

```
 regexp_substr( "YourField" , '-(?!.*-)(.*)$' )
```

This will return the substring after the last `-`. If you need to change the delimitor, just replace `-` with the proper character in the regex.

*Edit:* a short explanation of the syntax:

- `-` looks for all `-` characters
- `(?!.*-)` is a negative lookahead: it excludes all `-` characters that are followed by `.*-` (i.e. any number of characters, followed by a `-`). Thus, `-(?!.*-)` selects only the last `-`.
- `(.*)` is the capturing group (i.e. what will finally be returned by the regex). By writing `(.*)` right after `-(?!.*-)`, you're saying: "return all the characters after the last `-`".

You can try and test it on [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/r/cW3kZ5/1) if you want to learn more on regexes.

Comment: This works well, thanks! I'm not too familiar with regex though, could you possibly explain this syntax?

Comment: You're welcome. Regexes are difficult to master, but they can solve any substring-related issue.

Comment: I've been using this for a little while and have noticed that if you use `[- ]` it will return characters that follow the final of either character (either a dash **or** a space), but the original syntax works fine for matching only characters that follow the final dash **and** space. Thanks again!

Comment: You're right (basic mistake...)! I'll edit my post. Thanks for this comment.